# How to attach file to email in Node.js using File Upload control

Tags: node.js

My Angular app sends a FormGroup to a Node.js server & then sends that form content via an Email.

At the moment, I can populate the email body like so:

```
<tr>
    <th>Town</th><td>${content['formBody']['personalInfo']['town']}</td>
</tr>
```

and so on...

But, my form also has a File Upload control which I want to use to add file attachments to the email also.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<td>${content['formBody']['send']['fileUpload']}</td>
```

But instead of the actual selected file, "object Object" is appearing in the email body currently.

Is there a way I can attach the selected files to the email using the above approach, or is there a different way? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using in Node.js for getting the files?
A few months ago I needed to upload files and used *Multer*, a npm package for handling formdata files in node js. With it, you can use the files received on the backend and put it on the email.

In the frontend file

```
//Method to do the request
superagent
.post(/register")
.attach("avatar", uploadedImage)
```

uploadedImage has the image content that you get in the VueJS component

In the backend file

```
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
import fs from 'fs-extra'

router.post('/register', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) => {
    return fs.readFile(req.file.path)
            .then(content => {
                // The content of the file
            })
}
```

For more information, here you have the answer [Accessing data sent as FormData using Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123204/accessing-data-sent-as-formdata-using-axios/53123987#53123987)

Does it help?

Comment: Currently, I'm just posting the form data to the server & adding that data to the email body as I've shown above. But I haven't done anything specific for the files.

Comment: Nevermind, my answer isn't correct. If you want to see if the file content is correct do JSON.stringify(content['formBody']['send']['fileUpload']) that will transform the object to string

Comment: I ran this in my Post: `var file = JSON.stringify(content['formBody']['send']['fileUpload'])
console.log("File Upload - " + file);`, & the following was outputted: **File Upload - [{"file":{},"id":0,"icon":"doc","src":{"changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity":"data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,"}}]**

Comment: Is this on the frontend ?

Comment: No, this is in backend, my Node.js (app.js)

Comment: So, you are not receiving the file correctly on your backend, the file object is empty. You should try my initial suggestion.